# assign a variable to a batch cmd from xml node

Tags: xml, variables, batch-file

i have an .xml doc that i would like to assign a node to a varible in my batch file. For example when called upon, i need the batch file to read the xml file and insert the file path into my batch to execute the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-05-29T01:21:53">
<playList>
<id>1</id>
<filepath>\\MOVIESERVER\Movies\somevideo.avi</filepath>
</playList>
```

i need to be able to assign the filepath to a variable to be placed into my batch

```
@echo off
"C:\VLC\VLC.exe" "FILEPATH_VARIABLE"
exit

can someone lead me in the right direction?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this in your batch script. Remove the `echo` if it looks ok.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%a in ('type "file.xml" ^|find /i "<filepath>" ') do set "variable=%%a"
echo "C:\VLC\VLC.exe" "%variable%"
pause
```